# Call a function in OCaml based on a string variable storing the function name

Tags: ocaml

Is there such a mechanism in OCaml, such that I could invoke a function dynamically based on a variable storing the function name, like what I can do in other scripting languages?

For example, I have written a function foo(). And I store the String constants "foo" somewhere in a variable "x". In JavaScript I'm able to do something like this `window[x](arguments);` to dynamically invoke the method foo(). Can I do something similar in OCaml?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the kind of thing that OCaml lets you do easily. The program definition, including the names of functions and so on, isn't available for the program itself to manipulate.

A simple way to get this effect for a set of functions known ahead of time is to make a dictionary (a hash table or a map, say)  of functions using the function name as the key. Note that this will require the functions to have the same type (which is a feature of OCaml not a problem :-).

Comment: Is this because OCaml is a strongly-typed language? For the dictionary, would it be possible that you show me some very simple codes?

Comment: You can use a hash table. Here is a tutorial: http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/hashtbl.html

Comment: @MartinJambon Yes, I know. But do you know the syntax of writing the function as the value of the hashmap and then invoke it based on the key?

Comment: @MartinJambon Okay never mind, I've found out by myself.